# JPA - Wrong number of column of same class. should be 2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I trying to map my class to database,the class reference to itself by "id_comment_parent", but when running a test, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.ecommerce.entities.Comment from com.ecommerce.entities.Comment has the wrong number of column. should be 2
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:646) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:102) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1814) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.10.Final.jar:5.4.10.Final]
```

these is my classe:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment", catalog = "Ecommerce_db")
public class Comment implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "idComment", column = @Column(name = "id_comment", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "idCommentParent", column = @Column(name = "id_comment_parent", nullable = false)) })
    private CommentId id;
    @Column(name = "id_user", nullable = false)
    private long idUser;
    @Column(name = "comment", length = 65535)
    private String comment_1;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_comment_parent", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Comment comment;

}
```

anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `CommentId` that represents de Primary Key of `Comment`has more that one column. So the ForeignKey must have more than one JoinColumn too.

Besides, it seems that you are mixing the fields of your primary key and your foreign key, as you have id_comment_parent in both primary key and foreign key.

You actually have comment entities with the same id_comment but with different id_comment_parent? It that's not the case, I think that a more coherent mapping would be that id_comment is the primary key, and id_comment_parent is the foreing key. Something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comment", catalog = "Ecommerce_db")
public class Comment implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_comment", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "id_user", nullable = false)
    private long idUser;
    @Column(name = "comment", length = 65535)
    private String comment_1;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_comment_parent")
    private Comment parent;
}
```

Comment: i try to add   `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "id_comment_parent", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false),
   @JoinColumn(name = "id_comment", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    }) `        It gives the same error

Comment: What are the fields of `CommentId`?, it seems that you are using `id_comment_parent' as both part of the primary key and foreign key? It can't be booth

Comment: fields of CommentId is: `public class CommentId{

 private long idComment;
 private long idCommentParent;}`

Comment: Why do you need idCommentParent on your primary key? Isn't idComment enough as primary key? idCommentParent should be the foreing key that references idComment.

Comment: I would like it to be placed when a response to a comment means a comment that can contain many comments

Comment: A comment my contain many comments. Thats modelled with the @ManyToOne relationship. The question is if id_comment is unique. If it's unique you don't need any other field in the id/ primary key